# No sound after installing K-lite Mega Codecs: AC3, Audio Switcher: Out?

Tags: windows-7, audio, codec

I've installed K Lite Mega Pack 13.1.9 and I tried to play a DVD, and the following error pops up in MPC-HC player. Daum Potplayer plays it but the video is somewhat garbled and there is no sound. VLC plays it alright thanks to its internal codecs.

I had Windows Media Player disabled. I've re-enabled it but it didn't solve the issue.

I've installed ffdshow as a separate installation and it didn't solve the issue.

Windows 7 Pro, Intel(R) Pentium (R) D

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution for MPC-HC player is to choose your own sound settings instead of the system default i.e. in my case Speakers (SoundMAX Integrated Digital HD Audio)
[image]

The solution for Daum PotPlayer is to uninstall and reinstall choosing Download Additional Codecs option when installing.